# Custom Dreamweaver DocTypes

Tags: dreamweaver, html5, dtd

- Dreamweaver CS5 with Dreamweaver HTML5 Pack 1.2.7
- Windows 7 x64

When I go to create a new document and select the HTML5 DocType, Dreamweaver gives me the legacy encoding/character set declaration:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I want to replace it with the new, abbreviated style:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The relevant file seems to be `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\DocumentTypes\NewDocuments\Default.html`, which has a blank `charset`, that is then apparently replaced with the appropriate character set dynamically:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=">
```

I changed it, but then new documents show up like this:

```
<meta charset="">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

It seems Dreamweaver added the legacy declaration back in after my modification—and as far as I can tell, there's no way to specify that the `charset` definition should go in-between the quotes, either. Additionally, any modifications to `Default.html` apply to every DocType, whereas I only want this change to apply to the HTML5 DocType.

Is there anything in the configuration files that would allow me to make any of these customizations? If not, is there an extension that does it?